# Generate woocommerce coupon after gravity form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravityforms

I want a user to enter their email  in a gravity form and after submission  they are emailed a unique coupon code that expires after two weeks. I have cobble together code from a few other solutions and I am successful at creating the unique code. But I can't get it to create the coupon  in woocommerce.. Not being a PHP master I know I'm missing something obvious.

```
    //* Define options/constants
    define( 'ENGWP_FORM_ID', 276 ); // The ID of the form (integer)
    define( 'ENGWP_SOURCE_FIELD_ID', 2 );  // The ID of the form field holding the code (integer)
    define( 'ENGWP_CODE_LENGTH', 12 ); // Length of code (integer)
    define( 'ENGWP_CODE_CHARS', '1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM' ); // Available character for the code; default 0-9 and uppercase letters (string)
    define( 'ENGWP_CODE_PREFIX', '17-' ); // Custom prefix for the code (string); default empty
    define( 'ENGWP_DISCOUNT_TYPE', 'percent' ); // 'flat' or 'percent' (string)
    define( 'ENGWP_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT', 10 ); // Value of discount (integer); $ if 'type' is 'flat' and % if 'type' is 'percent'
    define( 'ENGWP_MAX_USES', 1 ); // Maximum number of uses per customer (integer)
    define( 'ENGWP_MIN_PRICE', 0 ); // Minimum price for discount to apply (integer); default none
    define( 'ENGWP_PRODUCT_REQS', '' ); // A comma-separated list of product IDs (string) the coupons apply to
    define( 'ENGWP_REQS_CONDITION', '' ); // How to apply the discount to those products (string); accepts 'any' (at least one product ID must be in the cart) or 'all' (all products must be in the cart)
    define( 'ENGWP_SINGLE_USE', 'use_once' ); // Whether the coupons generated can be used more than once by a single customer; default is set to one-time usage but can be set to false (boolean) for allowing multiple uses
    define( 'ENGWP_EXCLUDE_PRODUCTS', '' ); // A comma-separated list of product IDs (string) to exclude from discount-applicability

    $start_date = ''; # no date
    // $start_date = '01/01/1900'; # static date
    // $start_date = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime("yesterday") );

    $exp_date = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime("+14 days") );
    // $exp_date = '01/01/1900'; # static date
    // $exp_date = ''; # no date


    class GW_Create_Coupon {

       public function __construct( $args = array() ) {

    // set our default arguments, parse against the provided arguments, and store for use throughout the class
    $this->_args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'form_id'         => false,
        'source_field_id' => false,
        'plugin'          => 'wc',
        'amount'          => 0,
        'type'            => '',
        'meta'            => array()
    ) );

    // do version check in the init to make sure if GF is going to be loaded, it is already loaded
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );

}

public function init() {

    // make sure we're running the required minimum version of Gravity Forms
    if( ! property_exists( 'GFCommon', 'version' ) || ! version_compare( GFCommon::$version, '1.8', '>=' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    add_action( 'gform_after_submission', array( $this, 'create_coupon' ), 10, 2 );

}

public function create_coupon( $entry, $form ) {

    if( ! $this->is_applicable_form( $form ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $coupon_code = rgar( $entry, $this->_args['source_field_id'] );
    $amount      = $this->_args['amount'];
    $type        = $this->_args['type'];

    $plugin_func = array( $this, sprintf( 'create_coupon_%s', $this->_args['plugin'] ) );

    if( is_callable( $plugin_func ) ) {
        call_user_func( $plugin_func, $coupon_code, $amount, $type );
    }

}
    public function create_coupon_wc( $coupon_code, $amount, $type ) {

    $coupon = array(
           ‘post_title’ => $coupon_code,
    ‘post_content’ => ”,
    ‘post_status’ => ‘publish’,
    ‘post_author’ => 1,
    ‘post_type’ => ‘shop_coupon’
    );

    $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

    $meta = wp_parse_args( $this->_args[‘meta’], array(
    ‘discount_type’ => $type,
    ‘coupon_amount’ => $amount,
    ‘individual_use’ => ‘yes’,
    ‘product_ids’ => ”,
    ‘exclude_product_ids’ => ”,
    ‘usage_limit’ => ‘1’,
    ‘expiry_date’ => ”,
    ‘apply_before_tax’ => ‘no’,
    ‘free_shipping’ => ‘no’,
    ‘exclude_sale_items’ => ‘no’,
    ‘product_categories’ => ”,
    ‘exclude_product_categories’ => ”,
    ‘minimum_amount’ => ”,
    ‘customer_email’ => ”
    ) );

    foreach( $meta as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }
    }
        public function create_coupon_edd( $coupon_code, $amount, $type ) {

    if( ! is_callable( 'edd_store_discount' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $meta = wp_parse_args( $this->_args['meta'], array(
        'name'              => $coupon_code,
        'code'              => $coupon_code,
        'type'              => $type,
        'amount'            => $amount,
        'excluded_products' => array(),
        'expiration'        => '',
        'is_not_global'     => false,
        'is_single_use'     => false,
        'max_uses'          => '',
        'min_price'         => '',
        'product_condition' => '',
        'product_reqs'      => array(),
        'start'             => '',
        'uses'              => '',
    ) );

    // EDD will set it's own defaults in the edd_store_discount() so let's filter out our own empty defaults (their just here for easier reference)
    $meta = array_filter( $meta );

    // EDD takes a $details array which has some different keys than the meta, let's map the keys to the expected format
    $edd_post_keys = array(
        'max_uses'          => 'max',
        'product_reqs'      => 'products',
        'excluded_products' => 'excluded-products',
        'is_not_global'     => 'not_global',
        'is_single_use'     => 'use_once'
    );

    foreach( $meta as $key => $value ) {
        $mod_key = rgar( $edd_post_keys, $key );
        if( $mod_key ) {
            $meta[$mod_key] = $value;
        }
    }

    edd_store_discount( $meta );

}

function is_applicable_form( $form ) {
    $form_id = isset( $form['id'] ) ? $form['id'] : $form;
    return $form_id == $this->_args['form_id'];
}

    }


    //* Instantiate the class for EDD
    new GW_Create_Coupon( array(
'form_id'         => ENGWP_FORM_ID,
'source_field_id' => ENGWP_SOURCE_FIELD_ID,
'amount'          => ENGWP_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
'type'            => ENGWP_DISCOUNT_TYPE,
'meta'            => array(
    'excluded_products' => array( ENGWP_EXCLUDE_PRODUCTS ),
    'expiration'        => $exp_date,
    'is_not_global'     => 'not_global',
    'is_single_use'     => ENGWP_SINGLE_USE,
    'max_uses'          => ENGWP_MAX_USES,
    'min_price'         => ENGWP_MIN_PRICE,
    'product_condition' => ENGWP_REQS_CONDITION,
    'product_reqs'      => array( ENGWP_PRODUCT_REQS ),
    'start'             => $start_date,
)
    ) );


    /**
     * Generate the random codes to be used for the EDD discounts
     */

    //* Generates and returns the code
    add_filter( 'gform_field_value_uuid', 'gw_generate_unique_code' );
    function gw_generate_unique_code() {

$length = ENGWP_CODE_LENGTH;
$chars = ENGWP_CODE_CHARS;
$prefix = ENGWP_CODE_PREFIX;

$unique = '';
$chars_length = strlen( $chars )-1;

for( $i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++ ) {
    $unique .= $chars[ rand( 0, $chars_length ) ];
}

do {
    $unique = $prefix . str_shuffle( $unique );
} while ( !gw_check_unique_code( $unique ) );

        return $unique;

    }

    //* Checks to make sure the code generated is unique (not already in use)
    function gw_check_unique_code( $unique ) {

global $wpdb;

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'rg_lead_detail';
$form_id = ENGWP_FORM_ID; // update to the form ID your unique id field belongs to
$field_id = ENGWP_SOURCE_FIELD_ID; // update to the field ID your unique id is being prepopulated in
$result = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT value FROM $table WHERE form_id = '$form_id' AND field_number = '$field_id' AND value = '$unique'" );

if ( empty ( $result ) ) {
    return true;
} else return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WC_Coupon` to generate a coupon code. try the below code.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', array( $this, 'create_coupon' ), 10, 2 );

public function create_coupon( $entry, $form ){

    $coupon_code   = rgar( $entry, $this->_args['source_field_id'] );
    $date_expires  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+14 days'));
    $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // 'store_credit' doesn't exist

    $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
    $coupon->set_code($coupon_code);
    //the coupon discount type can be 'fixed_cart', 'percent' or 'fixed_product', defaults to 'fixed_cart'
    $coupon->set_discount_type($discount_type);
    //the discount amount, defaults to zero
    $coupon->set_amount($amount );
    $coupon->set_date_expires( $date_expires );
    //save the coupon
    $coupon->save();

}
```